# The permalinks in my wordpress post query will not work until the page is refreshed

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I put a query post on the front page of our site that pulls my own posts out of the company blog. It works fine, but that the permalinks do not work unless the page is refreshed after loading. Any help understanding why would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Here is the code:

```
<div style="float:left; display:inline; margin-left:385px; margin-top:-225px;">
<?php query_posts('showposts=5&author=4'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div>


<!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->

<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *the permalinks do not work* ?

Answer (score 1):

Try ending your while.

```
<?php the_title(); ?></a></div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```